# Accessing promise's elements which are objects and not simple types

Tags: angularjs, object, promise

I have a study, which has multiple cases and multiple executionMessages. Also each case has multiple executionSteps. I am able to access the study, the case and even each case's executionSteps. I cannot figure out why I cannot access the complete executionMessages. By that I meant each executionMessage has a type, message which are accessible but any objects inside executionMessage is not accessing. Here it the code

```
        StudyService.studies.get({id: $routeParams.studyIdentifier}).$promise.then(function(study) {
                  $scope.study = study;
                  StudyService.executionMessagesForStudy.get({id: study.id}).$promise.then(function(executionMessages){
                      $scope.study.executionMessages = executionMessages;
                  });
                  for(var i=0;i<study.cases.length;i++){
                      var callback = callbackCreator(i);
                      StudyService.executionstepsForCase.get({id: $routeParams.studyIdentifier,caseId:study.cases[i].id})
                      .$promise.then(callback);
                  }
            });
    function callbackCreator(i) {
          return function(executionSteps) {
            $scope.study.cases[i].executionSteps = executionSteps;
          }
    }
```

Comment: The $scope.study,executionMessages = executionMessages does populate but not completely. Meaning the simply types inside executionMessage are populated but not the complex ones. For instance each executionMessage has a case and study object in it for backreference but it's not accessible.

Comment: What's callback creator? Why aren't you simply using `.then` and promises instead?

Comment: I had to use a callbackCreator(i) because it has to index thru the elements. That's the only way I got it to work based on a suggestion on here.

Comment: What do your objects returned form the API look like? specifically what is `study` and `study.cases`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `$resource` for your service types (a guess at the `.get().$promise` pattern you are using), From the docs:

> ...invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then rendered by the view.

see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

So your code can be simplified like this:

```
// get() returns an object that will "fill-in" with the attributes when promise is resolved
$scope.study = StudyService.studies.get({id: $routeParams.studyIdentifier})

$scope.study.$promise.then(function(study) {
     // again, executionMessages gets a placeholder that will be filled in on the resolved promise
     $scope.study.executionMessages = StudyService.executionMessagesForStudy.get({id: study.id});

     angular.forEach(study.cases, function(case, idx) {
        // again, executionSteps is a placeholder that will be filled in on the resolved promise
        var executionSteps =  StudyService.executionstepsForCase.get({id: $routeParams.studyIdentifier, caseId: case.id})
        // not sure if ordering is important, the service calls can return in any order
        // so using push can produce list with elements in any order.
        $scope.study.cases.push(executionSteps);
     });
 });
```

You still need to use the `study.$promise` to get the nested data after the first service call resolves.

Comment: What about the $scope.study.executionMessages call, why don't we use a promise on that one too. It doesn't not seem to come through otherwise

Comment: And what about the $scope.study, where are you resolving that in your code? Please let me know

Comment: The first line returns an "empty reference" per the documentation linked to. When the API call returns (i.e. the promise resolves) `$resource` takes care of "filling in" the empty reference. If you're still having trouble I'd suggest reading the documentation on `$resource` and perhaps not trying to add attributes to the `$scope.study`, maybe instead have a `$scope.executionMessages` and `$scope.cases` where you build separate objects for this data.